# Show / Hide div not working click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've made an agenda which got events and once i click on days , i would like to click on a day and this will show the event but this don't work

I want to show the class="info"

i've tried like that but this don't work

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggleNextInfo', function () {
$(this).nextAll('.info').toggle();
```

});

maybe it's because of css too ?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggleNextInfo', function () {
    $(this).next('.info').toggle();
});
```

```css
/*[fmt]0020-000A-3*/
body{  background:#EEEEEE;  letter-spacing:1px;  font-family:Helvetica; padding:10px;}
.year{  color:#D90000;  font-size:85px;}
.relative{  position:relative;}
.months{}
.month{  margin-top:12px;}
.months ul{  list-style:none;  margin:0px;  padding:0px;}
.months ul li a{  float:left;  margin:-1px;  padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;  color:#888888;  text-decoration:none;  font-size:35px;  font-weight:bold;  text-transform:uppercase;}
.months ul li a:hover, .months ul li a.active{  color:#D90000;}
table{  border-collapse:collapse;}
table td{  border:1px solid #A3A3A3;  width:80px;  height:80px;}
table td.today{  border:2px solid #D90000;  width:80px;  height:80px;}
table td.padding{  border:none;}
table td:hover{  background:#DFDFDF;  cursor:pointer;}
table th{  font-weight:normal;  color:#A8A8A8;}
table td .day{  position:absolute;  color:#8C8C8C;  bottom:-40px;  right:5px;  font-weight:bold;  font-size:24.3pt;}
table td .events{  position:relative;  width:79px;  height:0px;  margin:-39px 0px 0px;  padding:0px;}
table td .events li{  width:10px;  height:10px;  float:left;  background:#000;  /*+border-radius:10px;*/  -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px;  -khtml-border-radius:10px;  border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  margin-left:6px;  overflow:hidden;  text-indent:-3000px;}
table td:hover .events{  position:absolute;  left:582px;  top:66px;  width:442px;  list-style:none;  margin:0px;  padding:11px 0px 0px;}
table td:hover .events li{  height:40px;  line-height:40px;  font-weight:bold;  border-bottom:1px solid #D6D6D6;  padding-left:41px;  text-indent:0;  background:none;  width:500px;}
table td:hover .events li:first-child{  border-top:1px solid #D6D6D6;}
table td .daytitle{  display:none;}
table td:hover .daytitle{  position:absolute;  left:582px;  top:21px;  width:442px;  list-style:none;  margin:0px 0px 0px 16px;  padding:0px;  color:#D90000;  font-size:41px;  display:block;  font-weight:bold;}
.clear{  clear:both;}
```

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/date.ico" />
        <title>Calendrier</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style5.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){
               $('.month').hide();
               $('.month:first').show();
               $('.months a:first').addClass('active');
               var current = 1;
               $('.months a').click(function(){
                    var month = $(this).attr('id').replace('linkMonth','');
                    if(month != current){
                        $('#month'+current).slideUp();
                        $('#month'+month).slideDown();
                        $('.months a').removeClass('active'); 
                        $('.months a#linkMonth'+month).addClass('active'); 
                        current = month;
                    }
                    return false; 
               });
            });

        </script>


        <script  type="text/javascript" >
$(document).on('click', '.toggleNextInfo', function () {
    $(this).next('.info').toggle();
});
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require('config.php'); 
        require('date.php');
        $date = new Date();
        $year = date('Y');
        $events = $date->getEvents($year);
        $dates = $date->getAll($year);
        ?>
        <div class="periods">
            <div class="year"><?php echo $year; ?></div>
            <div class="months">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($date->months as $id=>$m): ?>
                         <li><a href="#" id="linkMonth<?php echo $id+1; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode(substr(utf8_decode($m),0,3)); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php $dates = current($dates); ?>
            <?php foreach ($dates as $m=>$days): ?>
               <div class="month relative" id="month<?php echo $m; ?>">
               <table>
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <?php foreach ($date->days as $d): ?>
                                <th><?php echo substr($d,0,3); ?></th>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                       <?php $end = end($days); foreach($days as $d=>$w): ?>
                           <?php $time = strtotime("$year-$m-$d"); ?>
                           <?php if($d == 1 && $w != 1): ?>
                                <td colspan="<?php echo $w-1; ?>" class="padding"></td>
                           <?php endif; ?>


              <td     <?php if($time == strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))): ?> class="today" <?php endif; ?>>     <a class="toggleNextInfo"  > TEST </a>
                                <div class="relative">
                                    <div class="day"><?php echo $d; ?></div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="daytitle">
                                   <?php echo $date->days[$w-1]; ?> <?php echo $d; ?>  <?php echo $date->months[$m-1]; ?>
                               </div>
                               </br>
                               <ul class="events">
                               </br>
                               </br>


                                   <?php if(isset($events[$time])): foreach($events[$time] as $e): ?>

                                      <div class="info" >
                                        <li > <?php echo $e; ?></li>
                                            <li>    
                                                    <form>  <input type="radio"  name="Disponibilité" value="Disponibilité"> Choisir cette disponibilite
                                                            <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer"> 
                                                    </form>
                                            </li>
                                    </div>

                                   <?php endforeach; endif;  ?>
                               </ul>
                           </td>
                           <?php if($w == 7): ?>
                            </tr><tr>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                       <?php if($end != 7): ?>
                            <td colspan="<?php echo 7-$end; ?>" class="padding"></td>
                       <?php endif; ?>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
               </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


</br>
</br>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder why did you put all the `PHP` script in the snippet window that says `HTML`....

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next()` would find a DOM element that immediately follows `this`, but in you example `.toggleNextInfo` does not have a `.info` node following it.

[`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) would be better if your elements were on the same level.

You need to think through what html structure you have, because that informs your decisions with jquery. Not only are these two elements not siblings, but they're not at the same nesting level.

```
.toggleNextInfo
ul
  li
  li
    .info
```

Since these are likely to change, I generally prefer using `find`. There are several ways you can do this, but this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggleNextInfo', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.info').toggle();
});
```

Comment: i've tried like that but this don't work

$(document).on('click', '.toggleNextInfo', function () {
$(this).nextAll('.info').toggle();
});

maybe it's because of css too ?

Comment: See my answer revisions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i think the problem will be solved soon but i still have the problem with :hover i think as you can see the events can't stay once i click . 

try to go on September 
Here's the calendar 




http://esig-sandbox.ch/paintball/calendrierClient2.php